# Ansible - Looping through a list of nested Dictionaries

Tags: loops, nested, ansible, nested-loops

I have some problems creating a loop that works for the following nested structures:

1st level:

```
DeviceList = [Device1, Device2, Device3, etc..]
```

2nd level: Each device is a dictionary structure as follows:

```
Device1 = {
    "description" : "string",
    "Id": "Value",
    "DeviceIPs": Dictionary
}
```

3rd level: DeviceIPs is a dictionary where the key is one of the IPs assigned to the device converted to a string.

```
"DeviceIPs" = {
    "IP1": { "description": "string1", "interface": "eth0", "mask":"subnet_mask1" },
    "IP2": { "description": "string2", "interface": "eth1", "mask":"subnet_mask2" },
    "IP3": { "description": "string3", "interface": "eth2", "mask":"subnet_mask3" },
    etc..
}
```

Ideally, I need to create a loop for the the keys of "DeviceIPs" so:
"IP1"
"IP2"
"IP3"
possibly based on the inner value (for instance matching a when condition like interface == "eth1")

I have tried different ways but I really can't come out with anything that works.. any idea?

Comment: Could you post the exact question? I guess `json_query` would fit, but I'm not sure, as you don't post what you really need.

Comment: Hi Konstantin,

I actually managed to make it work with json_query filter. 
My problem was to loop through the IPs used as keys in the DeviceIPs dict, given DeviceList.
I changed the DeviceList to be a dictionary: DeviceDict and used json_query as follows:

    tasks:
        - debug:
              msg:  "IP: {{ item }}"
          with_items: "{{ DeviceDict  | json_query('*.DeviceIPs.keys(@)') }}"


This will loop through all the possible device records in DeviceDict and get the keys in DeviceIPs which are indeed the IPs. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try reorganizing your variables to loop over eth1. For example:

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    - DeviceList: 
        - Device:
            description: string
            Id: Value1
            DeviceIPs:
              - eth0: { "description": "string1", "ip": "value1", "mask":"subnet_mask1" }
              - eth1: { "description": "string2", "ip": "value2", "mask":"subnet_mask2" }
              - eth2: { "description": "string3", "ip": "value3", "mask":"subnet_mask3" }
        - Device:
            description: string
            Id: Value2
            DeviceIPs:
              - eth0: { "description": "string1", "ip": "value1", "mask":"subnet_mask1" }
              - eth1: { "description": "string2", "ip": "value2", "mask":"subnet_mask2" }
              - eth2: { "description": "string3", "ip": "value3", "mask":"subnet_mask3" }


  tasks:
    - debug: var=item.1.eth1.ip
      with_subelements: 
        - "{{ DeviceList }}"
        - Device.DeviceIPs
```

Comment: Hi Christina,

Thanks for the advice but that structure does not really work for me becaue, in DeviceList, I need a device identifier (e.g. Device1, Device2, Device3, etc..) and not a fixed key value: "Device" and subelements does not work in that case..

Answer (score 0):

Just for wider audience, I managed to do what I want in the end, using json_query filter.
I changed the fist level structure from a list (DeviceList) to a Dictionary (DeviceDict) and used the following json_query@

```
tasks:
  - debug: msg: "IP: {{ item }}" 
    with_items: "{{ DeviceDict | json_query('*.DeviceIPs.keys(@)') }}
```

This loops through all the possible device records in DeviceDict and get the keys in DeviceIPs which are indeed the IPs.

thanks everyone!